# Time between discord message sends not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I am creating an event to listen when there is a message and tell the time from when the last message that was sent. But I can't seem to figure out how to do just that. (I used `message.author.lastMessage.createdTimestamp - new Date().getTime()`) This does not seem to create a consistent time when I test it out. Any help on what's wrong or anything I need to fix would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to keep it simple and only use Dates.

```
// takes a User and returns the milliseconds of difference between now
// and the last message, if there's one.
function lastDiff({ lastMessage }) {
  if (lastMessage) return new Date() - lastMessage.createdAt;
}

lastDiff(message.author);
```

Keep in mind that this can't always print the same number since milliseconds can change between a check and the next one.
Once you have the milliseconds, you can format them as you want.

Comment: So it seems by the numbers I logged that discord might be taking the message that was just sent and saying that **that** was the last message. Is there any way around this since I'm using a message event.

Comment: You could loop through every channel in the guild and fetch the last message in every channel, then compare them, but it's not very efficient. You could also keep track in your bot's memory of the last message (or its Date) for every user, and update it only after the last interaction, but that's not very efficient too. What do you need this thing for? Some sort of cooldown?